# Pure JS Color slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, addeventlistener

I have a slider with **.images class** as well as **previous-** and **next-button**.

I have defined colors in JavaScript like this:

```
let colors = ['red', 'green',];
```

Currently, when I click the next-button, red-color is shown. (Function below).

```
function nextSlide() {
  container.style.backgroundColor = colors[0];
```

What I would like to accomplish is **When you click the next button it will always show the next color from the let colors array(or whatever this way of defining colors is called). On the opposite, when you click the previous-button, the slider should show the previous color from the array**.

You can find the full source code below.

```js
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');
const container = document.querySelector('.images');

let colors = ['red', 'blue',];

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', prevSlide);

function nextSlide() {
  container.style.backgroundColor = colors[0];
}

function prevSlide() {
  container.style.backgroundColor = colors[1];
}
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.images {
  background-color: #4047c9;
  flex: 0 0 80%;
  min-height: 70vh;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.prevBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.nextBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
  <div class="images">
    <button type="button" class="btn prevBtn">Prev Btn</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn nextBtn">Next Btn</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last slide when clicked to also go to the first, and the first slide when left clicked go to the last, you can use the modulus trick.

`slideslength + currentslidenumber + directions %(modulus) slidelength`

Below is an example.

```js
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');
const container = document.querySelector('.images');

let colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue',];
let currentSlide = 0;

function updateSlide(direction) {
  currentSlide = 
    (colors.length + currentSlide + direction)
    % colors.length;
  container.style.backgroundColor = colors[currentSlide];
}

updateSlide(0);

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', prevSlide);

function nextSlide() {
  updateSlide(+1);
}

function prevSlide() {
  updateSlide(-1);
}
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.images {
  background-color: #4047c9;
  flex: 0 0 80%;
  min-height: 70vh;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prevBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.nextBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
    <button type="button" class="btn prevBtn">Prev Btn</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn nextBtn">Next Btn</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfectly, thank you. I will mark this as an answer. I will start playing with this, but maybe you can advice me beforehand, would this also work with images?

Comment: Yes, images should not be a problem.  Just place image urls in your array and then update `backgroundImage` property instead of the `backgroundColor`.

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make a counter and on every function call increment or decrement it based on prev or next call. Make conditions so that it does not go negative and it does no go over length of the array and give colors using this counter as index of color array

```js
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');
const container = document.querySelector('.images');

let colors = ['red', 'blue','green','yellow'];

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', prevSlide);
var i=0;
function nextSlide() {
if(i>=colors.length-1)
i=0;
if(i<0)
i=colors.length-1;
  container.style.backgroundColor = colors[i++];

}

function prevSlide() {
if(i>=colors.length-1)
i=0;
if(i<0)
i=colors.length-1;
  container.style.backgroundColor = colors[i--];
}
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.images {
  background-color: #4047c9;
  flex: 0 0 80%;
  min-height: 70vh;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prevBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.nextBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
    <button type="button" class="btn prevBtn">Prev Btn</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn nextBtn">Next Btn</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey, and thanks for the help. This worked! I am gonna mark it as an answer as well.

Comment: Ups, sorry I did not know I can only add one answer :/

Comment: Mark the answer as correct which you think helped you in a better way

Answer (score 1):

```
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');
const container = document.querySelector('.images');

let colors = ['red', 'blue',];

let index = 0;

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', prevSlide);

function nextSlide() {
  container.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
  if(index <= colors.length){
    index++;
  }else{
    index = 0;
  }
}

function prevSlide() {
  container.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
  if(index <= colors.length){
    index--;
  }else{
    index = 0;
  }
}




<div class="images">
    <button type="button" class="btn prevBtn">Prev Btn</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn nextBtn">Next Btn</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: By using a counter and make it increase/decrease based on next/previous, you can achieve color sliding functionality

Comment: A little tip, the OP supplied a working snippet.   If you click the `Copy Snippet to answer`  you can modify it and make it runable like the OP's.  Also don't comment to your own answer, place the above text in your answer, you can click the `edit` link to update your answer with extra info.  And lastly asking for people to mark you answer as correct is not the done thing.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the info on how to put code in answer so it can be a runnable snippet ! As i am new to answering questions, i might make such mistakes. And i am asking if questioner finds my answer useful then only mark it so it can benefit to both of us. Again thanks !!

Comment: You code will not work on the first click because you are changing indexes after setting the background.

Comment: Hey, and thanks for the answer! This basically works, but has the same problem as one of the other answer on this thread. Next-button with this code only works once so if you go through the slides and then back, next-button does not change slides anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there, just implement an `index` to store the current position of your color array:

```js
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');
const container = document.querySelector('.images');

let colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green'];
let index = 0;
let length = colors.length;

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', prevSlide);

function changeColor() {
  container.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
}

function nextSlide() {
 if(index == length - 1){
   index = 0;
 }else{
   index++;
 }
 changeColor();
}

function prevSlide() {
  if(index == 0){
    index = length - 1;
  }else {
    index--;
  }
  changeColor();
}
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.images {
  background-color: #4047c9;
  flex: 0 0 80%;
  min-height: 70vh;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prevBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.nextBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
    <button type="button" class="btn prevBtn">Prev Btn</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn nextBtn">Next Btn</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey, and thanks for the answer! Tried this out and it works great, except one problem. If you go through all the slides with next-button and then go them through back again with prev-button, you cannot use the buttons anymore (the slides wont change anymore). Would you have any idea how to fix this? Also, it would be awesome if after last slide you would go back to the other end (I know I forgot to specify this).

Comment: @Tane - I'm not able to reproduce your issue. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @ellipsis Thank you for your help, that worked perfectly!